# troubleshooting python keyerror printing random values from dictionaries with list of values

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value-store, markov-chains

I'm trying to make a Markov text generator but I keep getting a `KeyError` that I don't understand.

In this function, I keep getting a `Keyerror` in the line `w1, w2 = w2, random.choice(self.wordlog[w1])`.

`self.gensize` is the number of words I want to generate,

`self.size` is the total number of words in my text,

`self.wordlog` is the dictionary - i.e. `{'secondly': ['because', 'because'], 'pardon': ['cried', 'cried', 'said', 'said', 'your', 'she'], 'limited': ['to', 'warranty', 'right', 'right', 'to'], etc...}`

```
def generate(self):
    startseed = random.randint(0, self.size - 1)
    w1, w2 = self.words[startseed], self.words[startseed+1]
    #at this point, w1 and w2 are a random word and a following word-i.e. alice ran
    wordlist = [] 
    for i in range(self.gensize):
        wordlist.append(w1)
        w1, w2 = w2, random.choice(self.wordlog[w1])
    #i.e. self.wordlog[alice] should return a list of all the values the word alice precedes
    wordlist.append(w2)
    print wordlist
```

When I run the function (`print markov("alice.txt", 5).generate()`), I just keep getting a `KeyError` - a different word each time (which is to be expected, as the starting seed and the random.choice will lead to this).

Anyone see what's wrong with this and how to fix this?

EDIT:

Here's the rest of the code, so you can see where `self.words` and everything else is coming from:

```
class markov(object):
    def __init__(self, filename, gensize):
        self.wordlog = {}
        self.filename = filename
        self.words = self.file_to_words()
        self.size = len(self.words)
        self.gensize = gensize

    def file_to_words(self):
        with open(self.filename, "r") as file_opened:
            text = file_opened.read().translate(None, string.punctuation)
            mixedcasewords = text.split()
            words = [x.lower() for x in mixedcasewords]
            return words

    def doubles(self):
        for i in range((self.size)-1):
            yield (self.words[i], self.words[i+1])       

    def catalog(self):
        for w1, w2 in self.doubles():
            self.wordlog.setdefault(w1, []).append(w2)
        print self.wordlog
```

Comment: Of course you see a different word each time, because `w1` is random too, you used `random.randint()` to create the index that retrieves a string from `self.words`.

Comment: Next, you swap `w1` and `w2`, and store another random word in `w2`. Are you certain that all words thus picked are in `self.wordlog`?

Comment: You didn't show us what is in `self.words`, nor did you show that *all* words in the lists in the values of `self.wordlog` are also keys in that dictionary.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I editted the original post to add the rest of the code so you can see `self.words`

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because you're using `random.choice` with a `dict` instead of a `list` / `set` / `tuple`
It's difficult to say but maybe you should check `self.wordlog` just to make sure.

```py
for k,v in self.wordlog.items():
    if type(v) != list: print("This shouldn't happen! Check: '"+k+"'")
```

[EDIT]
Maybe it's just while trying to fulfill the given **gensize** reaches a key that doesn't exist.

```py
print markov("alice.txt", 5).generate()
```

starts a `for` loop with five iterations. For each of the iteration you should be sure that the randomly picked key `w1` is actually a key of the `wordlog`.
To ensure this isn't a problem you can do 2 things:

## Approach 1

Check `w1 in wordlog` or `else: break`. 
This approach may give a solution smaller than the asked **gensize**.

## Approach 2

Make sure it works for **ANY** given **gensize**.
You can do this easyly linking the wordlog keys and values in loops, 
like in `{'a':['b','a'],'b':['b','a']}`

Comment: i don't think that's the issue because, as shown above, `self.wordlog` has its values all stored in a list.

for instance, take this example: `thedict = {'Gutenbergs': ['Alices'], 'Wonderland': ['by'], 'Alices': ['Adventures', 'in']}`
`print random.choice(thedict["Alices"])` works fine, sometimes giving 'in', sometimes giving 'Adventures'.

Comment: is that `, etc... }` that bothers me. Are you sure you're not adding new content to the `wordlog` after creating it?

Comment: I've noticed one more problem. You set a stop point by argument lets say 5. So it stops when it reaches a len of 5. So what happens if the map of word to word cosen randomly has not enough len.<br>

Comment: That example i.e. `the dict  = {'Gutenbergs': ['Alices'], 'Wonderland': ['by'], 'Alices': ['Adventures', 'in']}` If you print: `print random.choice(thedict["Gutenbergs"])` it's okay says `'Alices'`. Then `print random.choice(thedict["Alices"])` gets, say `'Adventures'`. So if the given len is bigger than 2 it won't work with `print random.choice(thedict["Adventures"])`